# How can I interact with a RDS MySQL instance with Node.js Lambda function?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am attempting to access a MySQL database hosted on amazon RDS through amazon Lambda. I have .js files that I can run through cmd line on windows, but when I transfer to Lambda, I cannot connect to the database. I researched this issue thoroughly, and even after following this guide: [Redstapler AWS](https://redstapler.co/aws-lambda-tutorial-rds-mysql/), I receive a "process exited before completing request" error message.

My Code, copied from the above tutorial

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
host: "",
user: "",
password: "",
database: ""
});
exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {
context.callbackWaitFOrEmptyEventLoop = false;
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM testdata limit 10", 
        function(error,result,fields){
        connection.release();
        if (error) callback(error)
        else callback(null,result)   
        });
    });
};
```

Error Message received from Amazon Lambda

> Response:
>    {
>    "errorMessage": "RequestId: b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c Process exited before completing request"
>   }
>   Request ID:
>   "b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c"
>   Function Logs:
>   START RequestId: b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c Version: $LATEST
>   2018-06-11T20:48:01.478Z    b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c    Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
>       at Handshake. (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:164:17)
>       at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>       at Handshake.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at Handshake._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:129:8)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
>       at Protocol.handshake (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
>       at PoolConnection.connect (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
>       at Pool.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
>       at exports.handler (/var/task/main.js:11:6)
>   END RequestId: b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c
>   REPORT RequestId: b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c  Duration: 10074.63 ms   Billed Duration: 10100 ms   Memory Size: 1280 MB    Max Memory Used: 27 MB
>   RequestId: b5151db1-6db8-11e8-8004-1b9e8072561c Process exited before completing request

This tutorial is highly rated and seems reputable, but I am unable to replicate its success. The error seems to imply that the connection.release is located in the wrong spot, or that I need to have another way of ending the connection and returning it to the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see that RDS instance security groups allow access from lambda IP address range (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) or place the lambda in VPC from which RDS instance is accessible.By default lambda is not in VPC...

Answer (score 0):

Similar question:
[updated : AWS Lambda is not able to connect to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789982/updated-aws-lambda-is-not-able-to-connect-to-mysql/50790169#50790169)

Put console log statements to know if you are able to connect to RDS or not.

```
...
connection.release();
console.log(result);
if (error) callback(error)
...
```

Make sure you call pool.end() before calling callback function else lambda function execution won't be exited properly so you will get the timeout error.